# $q.All didn't wait for all promises finishes when cascading then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have been using $q.all for running an array of promise asynchronously. In one of the element of the array, I want to cascade the promise so that I want to finish the whole functions before jumping out to the outest then function. the code looks below:

```
$q.all([
        function1().then(function () { }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason) }),
        function2().then(function () { }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason) }),
        function3().then(function () { }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason) }),
        function4().then(function () { }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason) }),
        function5($q).then(
            function() {
                $q.all([
                    function51($q).then(function () { }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason) }),
                    function52($q).then(function () { 
                        someLogic();
                    }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason); }),
                ])})
    ]).then(function () {
        usSpinnerService.stop('spinner');

        if ($scope.errorList.length > 0) {
            showMessages($scope, $scope.errorList, "error");
        }
    });
```

It seems like the code went to execute "usSpinnerService.stop('spinner');" before it actually runs into function51 and function52. I am wondering is there anyway to make the outside $q.all to execute all of the functions? Thanks.

And I also found that addToErrorList($scope, reason) in each of the top four functions are run asynchronously. Is there anyway to make it run synchronously then execute the outest then function?

**Correction**: above paragraph is not correct. I have checked addToErrorList DOES run before outer then function is hit.

Comment: `return` is your friend here. Return the result of your inner `$q.all`.

Comment: callback hell seems to be possible even with promises :)

Comment: _Is there anyway to make it run synchronously then execute the outest then function_ - the most outer `then` callback won't be executed before `addToErrorList` is executed

Comment: did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40382807/2545680) help?

Comment: it helps sort of. I have another place having the same issue let me try again your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: just don't understand why my question is downvoted

Comment: @HanYiZhang I don't know, upvoted) Let me know if there's anything unclear or the solution doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `$q.all` here:

```
function() {
    return $q.all([
        function51($q).then(function () { }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason) }),
        function52($q).then(function () {
            someLogic($http, $scope, $q, sharedService);
        }, function (reason) { addToErrorList($scope, reason); }),
    ])})
```

Comment: Thank you! your suggestion definitely works for me after I excluded a lot of other issues.